# (gnome-control-center:24694) | bluethoot & App error |

Tags: apt, gnome, 20.04, bluetooth, gnome-control-center

When I was trying to open settings nothing happened. So I have reinstalled the data packages with `apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center`. When I tried to manually search for settings, I could not find it so I had to run it from the console with `gnome-control-center display`.
I have opened the console, but every time I select the Bluetooth and apps settings I get the following errors:

BT:
`(gnome-control-center:24694): Bluetooth-WARNING **: 08:58:31.260: Error setting property 'Discoverable' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "Set" with signature "ssv" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist (g-dbus-error-quark, 41)`

Apps:
`cc-applications-panel-Message: 08:54:40.704: No permissions store proxy yet, come back later`

Any ideas on how to resolve these errors?